# Implicit casting error occurs between data access library and xamarin models classes

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, casting, model, data-access

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms app for Android that stores data at google-firebase.
I have a dotNet standard library for data access and a XamarinForms Shared library.

I have implemented models in both libraries, the data access models are responsible for uploading and downloading data from google-firebase, and the shared library models are for data binding.
While I am fetching data by data access models, I can't put them in shared library models to bind to UI. It shows error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'DataAccess.Models.Child' to 'VaxinApp.Models.Child' - CS0029`

**Note**
I know why the error occurs but don't know how to handle it. I used explicit casting, but it doesn't help.
**Update**
I might be violating design patterns or principles like `SOLID`, `DRY` while implementing the access layer point me them as well.

Comment: You cannot implicitly convert one reference type to another unless the compiler allows the specific conversion or the appropriate conversion operators are implemented. So check the `DataAccess.Models.Child` and `VaxinApp.Models.Child`. If it is possible, use the matching types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to Wendy's comment, we can't cast reference types, but we can do using a method in the model or doing its properties one by one, Like in the code snippet below.

```
var area = await firebaseHelper.GetArea();
            Area = new AreaModel
            {
                ClusterName = area.ClusterName,
                CHWName = area.CHWName,
                SocialMobilizerId = area.SocialMobilizerId,
                TeamNo = area.TeamNo
            };
```

See, I have initialized the class by adding properties of the other Class one by one.